# Forcing a controller's view into memory

Tags: iphone, performance, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

To address some performance issues, I started recycling some view controllers. However, the performance benefit of re-using a recycled controller's view is only present if that view has been drawn. If, for, example, I want to pre-populate the recycle queue with a controller but never place its view on screen, I get no such benefit.

How can I force the controller's view to be 'pre-rendered' and added to my queue such that when it is recycled I receive the performance benefit I am seeing from my other recycled controllers? I know that a controllers's view is created when first needed, but even adding the view and immediately removing it (before the parent view is displayed) doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: Is the performance issue memory, or cpu related?

Comment: CPU/gpu -instruments indicates that it is the drawing of the view

Answer (score 0):

My first thought on a quick and dirty way to do this is to just set the controller's view to hidden, and still have it "drawn" to the screen.

That bring said, I'm curious as to what the "performance issues" are that you're observing.  Depending on whether the creation of the UIViewController itself, or the UIViews that are causing a problem, then there may be a better overall solution to the problem.

Comment: I'm loading child view controllers on demand as the user pages across a scroll view. On slower devices there is a noticeable sticky point in the scroll as the controller is created and the view is built. Recycling the controllers instead of creating each one is helping.

Comment: I don't quite see your problem. Like you said, a ViewController's view is loaded when it is first accessed. If you just create your child ViewControllers when you create the parent and immediately access their view before placing them in a queue, your initial load time should be longer but you should have no performance hit when adding the child ViewController views to your scrollView. If that's what you'redoing and you still have a performance issue, can you post some code so we can see the problem?